# Open application with animation

Tags: android

Tell me how to implement an application opening animation like Twitter, Instagram, YouTube, etc.(Many applications have such an animation of opening an application). I tried to do this, created a simple Splash Activity, but I still have no such effect(First of all i see white screen and after Splash Activity)

[image]

**Solution**
Make style for `SplashActivity`:

```
<style name="SplashTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/logo</item>
</style>
```

And `@drawable/logo`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_image" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this animation codes. In the code below I used a button to perform the animation when clicked, you can apply it in SplashActivity.

Note: there are different animation options to use (Fade In / Fade Out, Zoom In / Zoom Out, Slide Up / Slide Down, Rotate in Clockwise or Anti-Clockwise, etc)

THE CODE ....

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
// boolean ElmoisShowing = true;

public void fade (View v) {
    ImageView elmoImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    //elmoImageView.animate().translationXBy(-100).setDuration(1000);
    // elmoImageView.animate().rotation(1800).setDuration(2000);
    //elmoImageView.animate().scaleX(0.5f).scaleY(0.5f).setDuration(1000);
    // Wrong - elmoImageView.animate().alpha(1).translationY(-100).rotation(500).setDuration(1000);
    
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  .......
  .......
    ImageView elmoImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    elmoImageView.setX(-1000); //send the image to the left corner (Unseen)
    elmoImageView.animate().translationXBy(1000).rotation(3600).setDuration(2000); //Loads the image from the left corner to screen
```

Comment: I was not talking about icon animation, I was talking about application opening animation